# CSS div using all space between two elements

Tags: css, html, positioning

my problem is that i want to place a div between two other elements.

Here is my fiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/NHBVa/1053/

```
div content
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I think you should use float to get your containers rendered

Comment: i want to have all these 3 elements (left,content,right) in one line. Left and right has 30px width. Content should have fill the space between

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want with the following styles:

```
.container {
    padding-left:30px; /* width of left container */
    padding-right:30px; /* width of left container */
}
.container > div {float:left;}

.left {
    margin-left:-30px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.right {
    margin-right:-30px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.content {
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NHBVa/1054/

Answer (score 0):

simply add `float:left;` for those three divs

```
.left,
.right,
.content{
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/NHBVa/1056/